# Improving time it takes to insert thousands of records using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a task in my program that is inserting thousands (94,953 in one instance and 6,930 in another) of records into my database using Entity Framework.

Right now I am doing this and calling the `.Add()` method for each record but it takes about 1 minute to insert the smaller batch and over 20 minutes for the larger batch. I have tried the `.AddRange()` method but that jumped the smaller batch to over 4 minutes.

Is there another approach with Entity Framework 6 or is this a limitation I have to live with? If it makes any difference, the data is going into a SQL Server 2012 R2 instance.

```
        var taskCodes = DynamicsHelper.GetTaskCodes(dynamicsSession, "01-01-1990");
        Console.WriteLine("Adding task codes to database.");

        using (var db = new JobSightDbContext())
        {
            foreach (var taskCode in taskCodes)
            {
                var projectID = db.ProjectCodes.Where(project => project.Code == taskCode.Item4).Select(project => project.ID).FirstOrDefault();

                if (projectID != 0)
                {
                    var newTaskCode = new TaskCode()
                    {
                        Code = taskCode.Item1,
                        Description = taskCode.Item2,
                        IsActive = taskCode.Item3,
                        ProjectID = projectID
                    };

                    db.TaskCodes.Add(newTaskCode);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} tasks added to the database.", db.TaskCodes.Count());
        }
```

Comment: I've removed the "Edit" part of the question - answers/reviews should be posted as answers, not as edits to the question (it's still in the [revision history](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/130070/2) if you need it) - self-reviews are perfectly fine, *encouraged* even!

Comment: Of course, if you go for speed, EF is not the best tool for bulk inserts. You need [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://blog.developers.ba/bulk-insert-generic-list-sql-server-minimum-lines-code/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're not making any changes to existing objects, you might set the `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`property of your context to `false`.

From MSDN:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the DetectChanges method is called automatically by methods of DbContext and related classes. The default value is true.

Calling the `Add` calls the `DetectChanges` method every time and is expensive. Turn it off and at the end, turn it on again.

Example:

```
using (var db = new DbContext)
{
    try
    {
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        //logic
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled  = true;
    }
}
```

More reading on this: [Secrets of DetectChanges Part 3](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/)

Also, you call the `SaveChanges` method **every** iteration in your loop. This means you make a call to your DB every iteration to persist that entity and is intensive and time consuming. Place that line of code outside your loop.

```
foreach (var taskCode in taskCodes)
{
    //logic
    db.TaskCodes.Add(newTaskCode);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

It's much more performant to make 1 call for many items than many calls for 1 item!

Here's an example question on StackOverflow about this: [Any difference between calling SaveChanges() inside and outside a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134232/any-difference-between-calling-savechanges-inside-and-outside-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: I edited your code example to be `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` as that is the proper call into it per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx hope you don't mind the small fix.

Answer (score 8):

You're doing this for each record:

```
var projectID = db.ProjectCodes.Where(project => project.Code == taskCode.Item4).Select(project => project.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

That alone is a massive performance issue. Instead, before looping through `taskCodes`:

- extract the distinct `Item4` (what a bad name, BTW) from your `taskCodes`,
- use those to retrieve the appropriate `ProjectCodes`
- and store the various combinations in a `Dictionary<T, T>`.

When you loop through `taskCodes` you can now use `TryGetValue` to retrieve the appropriate `projectID`.

---

However, considering the volume of data, it might be worthwhile for you to look outside of EF: consider `SqlBulkCopy`; [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548377/648075).

Comment: `Item4` is hard named by MS since I am using a `Tuple`, or at least I don't know how to change the name. I will give your extraction a try to see how much the time is improved. I was thinking about using `SqlBulkCopy` but this insert will almost never be ran, it is to just do the initial data import for the application so I kind of want to see what improvements can be done on the EF side without having to build out a whole ADO connection just for this.

Comment: Thinking on how to implement your suggestion of the extraction I am not seeing how it would work due to tasks having the same name (something I just realized). The data source I am pulling from allows multiple tasks with the same name, but only one task of a given name per project. Because of this I am not seeing a way to make the connection from the dictionary to the tuple.

Comment: @Matthew Key of the dictionary is the value of Item4, value is the value of projectID. And why are you using a Tuple with four items? Why not use a custom class with properly named properties?

Comment: @Matthew exposing a `Tuple` in a public API is bad design, because the client code has no way of telling the meaning of `Item1` from that of `Item4`. You don't *change the name*, you take 5 minutes to implement a tiny little public type that exposes the properties you need to carry around, and then you can rename them at will.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Thank you for your help. I had implemented your suggestions and did see a slight improvement in the speed but after using Abbas's suggestion, in tandem with yours, there was a significant speed improvement so I have accepted his as the answer since I can only accept on and his had the biggest impact on speed.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework isn't great for speed as others stated and SqlBulkCopy is a better tool for large inserts.

[EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/) is a nuget that encapsulates thr bulk copy such that it looks like its an EF operation. I've had some usage of it in the past.

Comment: note, this nuget is not free, there is a license fee